# XNamespace and XElement add an empty xmlns attribute on the first child element

Tags: c#, soap, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am trying to create the following XML string using XElement

```
<Issue xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <p>
        <Nombre>no</Nombre>
        <Descripcion>asdf</Descripcion>
    </p>
</Issue>
```

I've tried the following code, but this approach adds an empty `xmlns` attribute to the `p` element, which I don't want:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://tempuri.org/");

XElement e = new XElement(ns + "Issues",
                          new XElement("p", new XElement("Nombre", "nme"), 
                                            new XElement("Descripcion", "dsc")));
```

How can I prevent this issue?

**NOTE**:

I cannot use `XElement.Parse` like this because I need to build my soap request body dynamically:

```
var body = XElement.Parse("<Issue xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><p><Nombre>no</Nombre><Descripcion>asdf</Descripcion></p></Issue>");
```

I can't do this with a web service reference because is there an error when there exists a reference from Xamarin.

---

For now I am using the following workaround, but it is not the best solution, I guess:

```
var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
var xissue = xdoc.CreateElement("Issue");

var attr = xdoc.CreateAttribute("xmlns");
attr.Value = "http://tempuri.org/";
xissue.Attributes.Append(attr);

var xp = xdoc.CreateElement("p");
xissue.AppendChild(xp);

var xnombre = xdoc.CreateElement("Nombre");
xnombre.InnerText = "any value";
xp.AppendChild(xnombre);

var xdescription = xdoc.CreateElement("Descripcion");
xdescription.InnerText = "any value";
xp.AppendChild(xdescription);

var e = XElement.Parse(xissue.OuterXml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML, when an element does not have a namespace specified, then it inherits the namespace of its nearest ancestor that has a namespace.  So, in your sample XML, the `p` element and its children are actually all in the same namespace as `Issue`, because they do not have an `xmlns` attribute while `Issue` does.

To create this same structure using `XElement`, then, you need to make sure that *all* the elements specify the same namespace as `Issue`:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://tempuri.org/");

XElement e = new XElement(ns + "Issue",
                          new XElement(ns + "p", new XElement(ns + "Nombre", "nme"),
                                                 new XElement(ns + "Descripcion", "dsc")));
```

`XElement` is smart enough to recognize that when it is converted to string it does not need to repeat the `xmlns` attribute if it matches that of its parent.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QzYPoK

Conversely, if you just specify a namespace on the outer `XElement` but not on the inner ones, you are actually saying that you don't want the inner elements to have a namespace at all.  And so that results in an empty `xmlns` attribute on the first child element: it is effectively "opting out" of the parent namespace.